# Custom colormap boundaries for segmented colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have the following picture with data available for several vectors with some quantified feature:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
category = [0,0,0,0.1,0.4,0.9,1.5]
r = np.random.uniform(size=[len(category)*100]).reshape(len(category),100)

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(category), vmax=max(category))
bounds = np.array([0, 0.3, 0.5, 1.5])
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds, ncolors=3)
cmap = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=colors.ListedColormap(['green', 'blue', 'red']))
cmap.set_array([])
for no, cat in enumerate(category):
    ax.plot(r[no][r[no]>0.1],no*np.ones(100)[r[no]>0.1],'o',color=cmap.to_rgba(category[no]))
cbar = fig.colorbar(cmap, ax=ax, pad=0.01)
```

I am wondering is there any way to move colormap feature boundaries to correspond to the boundaries between vectors in the picture? (as denoted by black arrows)

I thought that `spacing='proportional'` will help me, however, it depends on the feature, and I want to make it dependent on the number of vectors having some range of features.

Additionally, is it possible to use these custom boundaries for gradient (not segmented) colormap?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to do what I asked for.
The idea is to create a new variable that will be dependent on the number of vectors in each group and use this variable with `spacing='proportional'`. Here is the MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
category = np.array([0,0,0,0.1,0.4,0.9,1.5])
r = np.random.uniform(size=[len(category)*100]).reshape(len(category),100)

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(category), vmax=max(category))

lev1 = 0.3
lev2 = 0.5

gr0 = (category<=lev1).sum()
gr2 = (category>lev2).sum()
gr1 = len(category) - gr0 - gr2
frac = np.array([gr0,gr1,gr2])/len(category)
bounds = np.array([0, frac[0], frac[1]+frac[0], 1])
gr_color = np.where(category<lev1,0,np.where(category>=lev2,1,frac[0]+frac[1]/2))

norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds, ncolors=3)
cmap = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=colors.ListedColormap(['green', 'blue', 'red']))
cmap.set_array([])
for no, cat in enumerate(category):
    ax.plot(r[no][r[no]>0.1],no*np.ones(100)[r[no]>0.1],'o',color=cmap.to_rgba(gr_color[no]))
cbar = fig.colorbar(cmap, ax=ax, pad=0.01,spacing='proportional')
dic = {bounds[0] : 0 ,bounds[1] : lev1, bounds[2] : lev2,bounds[3] : "1.5"}
labels = [bounds[i] if t not in dic.keys() else dic[t] for i,t in enumerate(bounds)]
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```

[image]